# How do I specify a loss matrix in rpart?

Tags: rpart

I have a basic question - how to I set up a loss matrix to weigh the cost of a false positive higher than a false negative? I am trying to produce a tree in rpart to classify a disease with high specificity.

Any advice would be appreciated, thanks

Answer (score 3):

Cost for mis-classification can be used as below:

```r
fit <- rpart(target ~ ., data=dataset, method="class", 
         parms=list(split="information", loss=matrix(c(0,1,2,0), byrow=TRUE, nrow=2)), 
         control=rpart.control(usesurrogate=0,maxsurrogate=0))
```

In the above example, I have considered that the cost of mis-classifying a positive example as a negative observation as 1 unit and cost of mis-classifying a negative example as positive as 2 units.

Comment: Could somebody pls break that down ?

Comment: The essential part is "loss=matrix(c(0,2,1,0), byrow=TRUE, nrow=2)". [Note that the use of "negative" and "positive" assumes here that the lower value indicates a negative case. The commentator assumes the opposite->(0,1,2,0)]. This creates a 2x2 loss matrix  with the elements in order: correctly classified negative cases (always a cost of 0), falsely classified negative cases (weighted with 2), falsely classified positive cases (weighted with 1), correctly classified positive cases (always a cost of 0).  In practice: a node with 0.4-0.6 would still be classified as negative, as 2*0.4>1*0.6.